# How to change the document root in PHP:7.1-apache from docker-compose.yml

Tags: apache, docker, docker-compose, environment-variables

I am trying to set up an environment for Laravel, and in that process I want to change my document root into a public folder. I made this work in a Dockerfile, but in reality I much rather want it in a docker-compose.yml file.

I feel that I have implemented the required environment commands from their [documentation](https://hub.docker.com/_/php/)

My code looks as

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3'

services:
    laravel:
        image: php:7.1-apache
        ports:
            - 8080:80
        env_file: ./.env
        environment:
            - "APACHE_DOCUMENT_ROOT=/var/www/html/public"
            - "sed -ri -e 's!/var/www/html!${APACHE_DOCUMENT_ROOT}!g' /etc/apache2/sites-available/*.conf"
            - "sed -ri -e 's!/var/www/!${APACHE_DOCUMENT_ROOT}!g' /etc/apache2/apache2.conf /etc/apache2/conf-available/*.conf"
        volumes:
            - ./src/:/var/www/html/
```

.env

```
APACHE_DOCUMENT_ROOT=/var/www/html/public
```

I first tried without the .env file, but then it gave me an error stating that the APACHE_DOCUMENT_ROOT variable was not set. Which is why I have the external .env file.

Can anybody lead me in a direction for improving this yml, so I have a different document root for my Apache?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

I found a solution for this issue. basically, it worked when I created a Dockerfile with build commands. So the following structure fixed the issue:

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'
services:
    web:
        build: .
        ports:
            - 80:80
        volumes:
            - ./src:/var/www/html
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM php:7.1-apache

ENV APACHE_DOCUMENT_ROOT=/var/www/html/public
RUN sed -ri -e 's!/var/www/html!${APACHE_DOCUMENT_ROOT}!g' /etc/apache2/sites-available/*.conf
RUN sed -ri -e 's!/var/www/html!${APACHE_DOCUMENT_ROOT}!g' /etc/apache2/apache2.conf /etc/apache2/conf-available/*.conf
```

Just remember to run **docker-compose build** before running the image (if anybody else have the same problem).

Comment: This is the solution, php doc doesn't specify that  APACHE_DOCUMENT_ROOT = DIRS INSIDE CONTAINER

Answer (score 4):

For testing temporary solutions, you can manually change the apache .conf file.
When your container is running, enter the bash:

```
docker exec -it your_container_name bash
```

Edit the content of the .conf file:

```
vim /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf
```

(if vim is not found, run `apt-get update` and  `apt-get install vim`)

Finally reload apache:

```
/etc/init.d/apache2 reload
```

Comment: Thank you, I needed to restart appache.

Answer (score -1):

You are running the sed command in "Environment section". Instead, you can use the "command" section to execute your sed command. These commands will run after entrypoint of Docker. So, your updated docker-compose.yaml will look something like as follow:

```
 version: '3'

services:
    laravel:
        image: php:7.1-apache
        ports:
            - 8080:80

        command:
            - export APACHE_DOCUMENT_ROOT=/path/to/new/root
            - sed -ri -e 's!/var/www/html!${APACHE_DOCUMENT_ROOT}!g' /etc/apache2/sites-available/*.conf
            - sed -ri -e 's!/var/www/!${APACHE_DOCUMENT_ROOT}!g' /etc/apache2/apache2.conf /etc/apache2/conf-available/*.conf

        volumes:
            - ./src/:/var/www/html/
```

Please update your docker-compose.yaml file and then let me know if it solves your problem

Comment: I have now tried that, but then the following error occurred:

    **laravel_1  | /usr/local/bin/docker-php-entrypoint: 9: exec: APACHE_DOCUMENT_ROOT=/var/www/html/public: not found
    laravel_laravel_1 exited with code 127**

I tried adding a command saying:

**- "mkdir -p /var/www/html/public"**

That didn't help. Am I missing something?

Comment: This doesn't work for me. I've tried using CircleCI 2.0, no luck.

Comment: Yeah, I ended up creating an image from scratch now. Just keeping this open a little longer.

Comment: The volume probably mounts after the command gets executed?