# Tell docker to run on another directory

Tags: docker, symfony

I'm installing a new Symfony project on Docker, and I have a little struggle with the directory management.

The main file for Symfony is the `public/index.php` file, which will load all dependencies on its parent folder. It's intended to be the root of the webserver.

But, with my current configuration, I have to call http://localhost:8001/public/ to get to this file.

```
version: '3'

services:
  php:
    container_name: php
    depends_on:
      - db
    build: .
    volumes:
      - .:/var/www/html
    ports:
      - "8001:80"
    restart: always
```

How can I tell docker to keep the same structure (putting all the files under `/var/www/html`), but to set the `/var/www/html/public` dir as the root ?

I feel like I'm just missing a specific vocabulary to look into the docs.

Comment: How is the post related to software develpoment?

Comment: On which StackExchange community should I ask the question ?

Comment: This sounds like something the [symfony community (`github.com`)](https://github.com/symfony/symfony#community) can answer. If symfony does not support it out of the box, then a reverse-proxy may be the way to go, but this heavily depends on how symfony is structured.

Comment: Are you able to set the [WORKDIR](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#workdir) in your Dockerfile?

Comment: Yes, I tried to set WORKDIR /var/www/html/public in the Dockerfile, but it didn't work. And as far as I understood, it's only meant to set a base path for next commands ?

Comment: this official php container should not be used in my opinion... its mixing php-fpm and php - one container per service. - older but still valid: https://cwd.at/blog/2019-12-08_docker-php-symfony/

Comment: @Rufinus it's allright for my development purposes. I use it only on my local env, to match my host's specs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to make it work, by following @kjc's answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51457728/4834168

Because I use php8-apache, I have to update apache's configuration tu update the document root.

So, all I had to do, is add these lines to my dockerfile:

```
ENV APACHE_DOCUMENT_ROOT=/var/www/html/public
RUN sed -ri -e 's!/var/www/html!${APACHE_DOCUMENT_ROOT}!g' /etc/apache2/sites-available/*.conf
RUN sed -ri -e 's!/var/www/html!${APACHE_DOCUMENT_ROOT}!g' /etc/apache2/apache2.conf /etc/apache2/conf-available/*.conf
```

This replaces all mentions to `/var/www/html` in Apache's configuration, to `/var/www/html/public`